# Why does running Mocha with Node.js work the first time, but not the second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have a testing app that has a UI that allows users to select certain tests and run those tests by clicking a button with Mocha. For some reason, the first time, the tests run and I get the passing results (2 passing or whatever). Any subsequent click of the button even with all the same values selected will run Mocha, but it runs 0 tests. So, it returns 0 passing. Here is the code that runs when the AJAX POST is made:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'list'
});

fs.readdirSync('node_modules/selenium-webdriver/nb_tests/').filter(function (file) {
  return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
}).forEach(function (file) {
  mocha.loadFile(path.join('node_modules/selenium-webdriver/nb_tests/', file));
});

// Now, you can run the tests.
mocha.run(function (failures) {
    process.on('exit', function () {
      process.exit(failures);
    });
});
```

Btw, when I console.log(mocha) right before running the tests they are identical on all requests. Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out...it seems that Mocha didn't like me creating a new instance for each POST. The code above was all contained in the route handler. So, here is what I did:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'list'
});

app.post('/runtest', function (req, res) {
    fs.readdirSync('node_modules/selenium-webdriver/nb_tests/').filter(function (file) {
        return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
    }).forEach(function (file) {
        mocha.addFile(path.join('node_modules/selenium-webdriver/nb_tests/', file));
    });

    mocha.run();
});
```